# How do I look for and exclude string regex literals from diff comparison?

Tags: regex, linux, diff

I'm trying to write a linux diff statement to ignore all line differences that have a literal string somewhere in them. (In my case I want to ignore lines with url differences.)

Currently I've tried

```
diff -I '^insert.*' file1.txt file2.txt > outputDiff.txt
```

The output here took out lines that started with insert, so that's a step in the right direction, but I need to remove a **longer string literal (url)** with lots of periods and slashes.

To be exact: I need to look for lines that have:

```
ta.com/nmo/nmdr/templates/nmdr.css\
```

somewhere in them, and exclude them from the diff result.

How do I look for a literal string with a regex that will work within a diff -I statement? (Include the start of the line and the end of the line if it's needed for my diff statement)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `.` and `\` in the regexp.

```
diff -I 'ta\.com/nmo/nmdr/templates/nmdr\.css\\' file1.txt file2.txt > outputDiff.txxdt
```

Answer (score 0):

In one command:

```
diff -I 'ta\.com/nmo/nmdr/templates/nmdr\.css\\' file1.txt file2.txt \
  > outputDiff.txt
```

This is escaping the special `.` character (which usually means "any character"), and also handling the literal backslash.

Or, you could do it (slightly less efficiently) in a chained command:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | fgrep -v 'ta.com/nmo/nmdr/templates/nmdr.css\\' \
  > outputDiff.txt
```

`fgrep`, or equivalently `grep -F`, stands for "fast grep" and automatically escapes special characters like `.`